# How do transitive dependencies work in Python pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have an automated machine build that installs a Python package (Package A) with a ton of dependencies (Packages X, Y, and Z).  Package A doesn't pin the versions of packages X, Y, or Z, so even though I pin the version for package A, there have been a bunch of times when my builds fail because of a breaking update in package X.

To fix this, I was planning on making a requirements.txt file that pinned explicit versions of A, X, Y, and Z (rather than just A, which is what happens now).  This should work assuming `pip` has proper support for both pinning and transitive dependency resolution.

It seems like this works with my current version of `pip`, but I've found a lot of conflicting information about how `pip` handles these things (eg, [this thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) with 100 comments talking about how `pip` dependency resolution isn't great).

So my questions:

1. How does dependency resolution work in `pip`?  If package A depends on X>=7, and my top-level requirements.txt specifies X==8, is it possible that `pip` would install X version 9 because it looks at A first and tries to get the most recent version of transitive dependencies?
2. Is there a canonical / authoritative source describing how dependency resolution works in `pip`?  The best I've been able to find is [this page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#satisfying-requirements), but some of the comments I've seen online make it seem like that page isn't 100% correct where transitive dependencies are concerned.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm very interested in finding out more about this as well and will provide some bounty points if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

pip introduced a [new resolver in 20.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/?highlight=resolver#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-3-2020) and from 21.0 this is now the default resolver.

The new resolver fixes the inconsistencies outlined in your first question and not only that. When dependency packages are inconsistent (e.g. X>=7 and X==6) it will reject the installation all together.

The new resolver is [resolvelib](https://github.com/sarugaku/resolvelib) based so you can find details about the algorithm there but pip also updated the [docs about dependency resolution](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/) with some details like the backtracking they do.